# uninstall sublime text from net beans IDE

Tags: netbeans

I just downloaded a zip folder of sublime theme and unzipped it. And I imported sublime theme successfully into my Net Beans IDE but, now I want to de-active sublime text from my IDE. How to uninstall sublime text from my IDE?

Comment: Do you mean [Sublime theme](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/51424/sublime-theme)?

Comment: yes sir, it appears like a black screen.....but, i want normal white screen which i used before

Comment: Have you checked Color/Look and feel options? Netbeans [has issue](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236584) similar to yours.

Comment: no....i didn't checked it

Comment: sir ,actually i just want to deactivate the imported sublime text theme and to get my normal net beans IDE.

Comment: Sure, basically Sublime theme just adds another profile so you can switch back to normal profile by selecting it in "Preferences > Fonts & Colors" or in "Miscellaneous > Windows > Look and Feel > Preferred look and feel"

Comment: sir,   In Tools>Options>Appearance>  inside Appearance 3 menus are there 1)Document Tabs 2)Windows 3)Look and Feel        inside Look and Feel  preferred  look and feel select box is there in that 4 fields are there 1)Metal 2)Nimbus 3)CDE/motif 4)GTK+ .But by default GTK+ was selected.but what you told is not there

Comment: thank you for your response...

Comment: thank you for your response...i got back to my normal profile.The solution for this is.....Go to Tools....Select options.....then u get a window that it contains General,Editor,Fonts&Colors,KeyMap ..and so on...then select Fonts & Colors....in that, Profile --select box is selected with a sublime theme.....then you have to select netbeans from the given options to get back to the normal profile .keep smiling..........

Comment: I'm happy that you found a correct answer, keep it up!

Comment: thank u so much sirr......

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about handling your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is.....Go to Tools....Select options.....then u get a window that it contains General,Editor,Fonts&Colors,KeyMap ..and so on...then select Fonts & Colors....in that, Profile --select box is selected with a sublime theme.....then you have to select netbeans from the given options to get back to the normal profile .keep smiling.........